# Como recuperar todos checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

No código abaixo, já tentei recuperar todos os checkbox mas não consigo trazer nada, eu não gostaria de colocar o ID, mas recuperar inúmeros checkbox selecionados, como que posso fazer? Coloquei apenas 2 como exemplo:(**Code Behind**)

```
<div class="form-group">                  
    <label for="teste" class="col-sm-2 control-label">teste</label>               
    <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6">     
        <asp:TextBox ID="teste" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckMed" runat="server" />
    </div>        
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckSun" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer isso no cliente ou no servidor?

Comment: Seria no codebehind

Answer (score 2):

Acho que não é a melhor maneira, mas você pode encontra-lo dessa forma:

```
CheckBox chkCheckMed= (CheckBox)PanelBar.FindControl("CheckMed");
```

`PanelBar` é apenas um exemplo. Você deverá colocar os seus itens dentro de um Panel com nome de sua preferência para funcionar como nesse exemplo.
Note que usar dessa forma induz a vários erros. Se por algum motivo o ID do item for alterado, por exemplo, ele já não encontrará o objeto.

Lembre-se que para usar o `checkbox`, você precisa chamar o `UI.WebControls`:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```